# JavaScript: Loop through string and return string + 'ay' if string contains vowel in first letter

Tags: javascript, string, loops, return, slice

I am trying to run a function that does pig latin.  I'm stuck on one of the first steps.

When I set the input argument equal to 'eat' => I want my code to return the string plus 'ay'.  Please see code below for if statement as well.

Instead, when I run my code it returns undefined.  I want it to return 'eatay'.  Why?

```
// Pig Latin

const pigify = (str) => {

  let sentSplit = str.split(' ')
  //console.log(sentSplit)

  for (let i=0; i<sentSplit.length; i++){
    //console.log(sentSplit[i])
    let element = sentSplit[i]

    console.log(element[0])

    if (element[0].includes('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')){
      return `${element}ay`
    }

    // else if (!str[0].includes('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') && !str[1].includes('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')){
    //   return `${str.slice(2)}${str.slice(0,2)}ay`
    // }

    // else if(!str[0].includes('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')){
    //   return `${str.slice(1)}${str[0]}ay`
    // }
  }
}

pigify('eat')
```

Comment: Read the documentation for includes again https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments to `includes()` wrong. The syntax is `container.includes(element)`, so it should be:

```
if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0])) {
```

Comment: that worked!  But now I'm having difficulty with not includes.  To do not includes is it the following: if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(!element[0]))

Comment: You put `!` before the entire expression: `!['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(element[0])`

Comment: thank you, both your original suggestion and the ! placement worked!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript itself provides the functions 'includes' and 'charAt'. Instead of splitting the string to characters array and finding the first element, str.charAt(0) can be used. and includes function searches through the array and returns true if any element matches.

```
const pigify = (str) => {
  if(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(str.charAt(0))) {
  return str+'ay';
}
```

Comment: Some words explaining how this code answers the OP's question would make your answer more useful.